# Prove normal of direct product of GL

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G=(\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \oplus \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R}))$ and let $H = \{(A,B) \in G \mid\det(A)=\det(B)\}$. Prove that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Mostly confused on what $G$ is.

Comment: $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of the $2\times 2$ invertible matrices with entries on the field, the group structure is given by matrix multiplication (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group). $G$ consists of pairs of elements of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. matrices) with the group structure given pointwise.

Comment: Sorry. I meant X as the direct product. (external direct product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is a collection of pairs of matrices, and $H$ contains those pairs that have the same determinant, with the operation defined by matrix multiplication component-wise.  For example,

$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)$$

is an example of an element in $H$ because both matrices have determinant $1$.

Now, see if you can prove that $H$ is normal using the fact that $\det(ABA^{-1})=\det(B)$.

Comment: Not this? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html

You mean det(B)?

Comment: Kronecker sum has nothing to do with this problem...

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a time on G/H ~= (R*,x)?
Not really sure how to use (aH)(bH)=abH.